# Use AngularJS Material components in Angular 2+ project

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-material, angular6

I develop in Angular 2+ for quite a while using Angular Material, but the documentation of AngularJS Material is more complete and wide then the one to Angular 2+, there is a way to use AngularJS Material components in an Angular 2+ project? More specific on Angular 6

Comment: did you see this site dedicated to Angular 2+ material https://material.angular.io/

Comment: and the "full" documentation at http://material.io

Comment: yes, as i said "but the documentation of AngularJS Material is more complete and wide **then the one to** Angular 2+" i know the existence of the Angular 2+ documentation, but the AngularJS doc has lot more components then the Angular 2+

Answer (score 4):

You will have to run both frameworks simultaneously to make it work. While that certainly is possible, it usually isn't desired, especially if there isn't a clear separation between where the AngularJS application and the Angular 2+ application ends and begins (for instance as there would be if you're migration an AngularJS application to Angular 4). AngularJS components, spread around an Angular 2+ application doesn't seem like a desirable situation.

Here are some additional issues:

Component names may clash
Routing may interfere with each other
Communication between AngularJS components and Angular 2+ components is difficult
I have two suggestions.

Either do away with the AngularJS dependency and clean up after the former co-worker.
Or, create thin wrapper components around Angular2 Material components, that has the same name and signature as the AngularJS material components. This is only possible if the components work somewhat similarly.
I recommend the first suggestion, since the latter might only be plausible for the most simple components.